# How to delete a directory on linux with name "-rf" using terminal command?

Tags: linux, command

It may be a silly problem but I really want to know how to delete a directory with the name "-rf".

I have been trying many ways but nothing works.

[image: Screenshot about my tried command]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your answer

rm -rf ./-rf/